# Using RFID and fingerprint sensor together

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit, rfid

I am using both an RFID and a fingerprint sensor in my project. When running the program, the RFID is detected but the fingerprint sensor is not detected and hence my code is not going forward.

Here is my code

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define SAD 10
#define RST 5

MFRC522 nfc(SAD, RST);

uint8_t id;
uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll();
int getFingerprintIDez();

// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino (WHITE wire)
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Looking for MFRC522.");
  nfc.begin();
  byte version = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! version) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find MFRC522 board.");
    while (1); //halt
  }

  Serial.print("Found chip MFRC522 ");
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. 0x");
  Serial.print(version, HEX);
  Serial.println(".");
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Fingerprint and RFID Test");

  finger.begin(57600);
  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1);
  }    
}

char abc;

void loop() {
  abc = Serial.read();
  switch (abc) {
    case '1': {
      // enroll method
    }
    break ;
    case '2': {
      // verify method
    }
    break;
    case '3': {
      // rfid method
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does happen?

Comment: serial monitor is not showing anything. when I run the rfid and fingerprint code individual they both are working correctly but when join them not working

Comment: Literally nothing?  Not even `Fingerprint and RFID Test` in your `setup()`?

Comment: `fingerprint and rfid test` is working if I write `rfid.init()` after this code. if I write before `fingerprint and rfid test` then it shows nothing

Comment: Could you replace your code with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? You could also edit your question to remove irrelevant information - such as the stuff about the switch statement. Help us to help you.

Comment: Get rid of the `Serial.begin(9600)`. You're accidentally changing the Serial baud rate without doing the same in your serial monitor so you'll probably see gibberish, if anything.

Comment: ya I deleted the `Serial.begin(9600)` and it worked

Comment: @TisteAndii would you mind turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `Serial.begin(9600)`. You're accidentally changing the `Serial` baud rate without doing the same in the serial monitor so you'll probably see gibberish, if anything.